# How to send data from one Fragment to another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-webview

Hi I know there are answers of this question. I have tried all of them but it is not working in my app.
I am developing an app that has 3 Fragment activity. First fragment shows a website, second fragment has listview and third Fragment has another listview. Now I want to send URL from third fragment to first fragment when user clicks on listitem..This is what I have done.

I am sending string url from this Fragment to first fragment.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        FragmentC fragment = new  FragmentC();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("position", "http://www.facebook.com");            fragment.setArguments(bundle);}
});
```

This is first fragment where I need the url and Want to show in the webview.

```
String url="http://www.hotelsearcher.net/";
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args  != null){
        url = args.getString("position");
        }
        WebView webView= (WebView) V.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

When I click on list item I don't see anything . It does not redirect me to the first fragment.Please help me..

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use **Bundle** to send `String`:

```
//Put the value
YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

In `onCreateView` of the new **Fragment:**

```
//Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

Comment: what do you mean by YourNewFragment ?

Comment: Is your "Another fragment". Is the fragment you want to receive the String value.

Comment: what does the container refer to?

Comment: Is the id declared in your activity xml file.  

android:id="@+id/container"

Comment: ok..It works..It redirects to the first Fragment.But it is showing Dialog to choose a broswer to view the website rather than showing the website on my webview..Can you help me on this.I will accept the answer.:)

Comment: please close this question and open another one with the new question. I try to help you in the new question.

Comment: I have accepted the answer..I cant post another question in 90 minutes.I need this done urgent. Can you please help me here.. I promise I will post another question and let you know and accept your answer if my problem is  solved.

Comment: say here in comments what is the problem

Comment: try to put this in webview: myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: Great ..:) thank you..It works.. I will post any another question and let you know..

Comment: please, send-me a comment here before post the question

Comment: Now probably you can post you new question. Please do it and let me do the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558423/string-url-sent-from-another-fragment-is-not-showing-in-webview-in-current-fra

this is the question.

Answer (score 5):

1.If fragments are hosted by same activity- You cannot cast an intent to Fragment. Fragment acts as a part of Activity, it is not an activity by itself. So to share a string between fragments you can declare a static String in Activity. Access that string from Fragment A to set the value and Get the string value in fragment B.

2.Both fragments are hosted by different Activities- Then you can use putExtra to pass a string from Fragment A of Activity A to Activity B. Store that string in Activity B and use it in Fragment B.

Comment: I have different Fragment and I want to send String from Fragment to another fragment.

Comment: yes, understood but that Both fragments are hosted by Same Activity??

Answer (score 2):

You have to attach your bundle to your fragment.

```
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and after that change or replace the new fragment.

You have to be sure that the String is in the new Fragment. Debugging!!

Answer (score 0):

You can send data by two ways 
First when you want to start that fragment while sending data

```
SecondFragment ldf = new SecondFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

Second, when you want to send data without open your fragment

```
FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragContainer1, new ModelListFragment(), FRAG_MODEL_LIST);
ft.add(R.id.fragContainer2, new TrimListFragment(), FRAG_TRIM_LIST);
ft.commit();

Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MainActivity.FRAG_MODEL_LIST);
Log.d("MY", "found fragment: " + (fragment != null));
```

Comment: How do I receive the data in the second fragment?