# webView loadUrl opens browser choice dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have three Fragment. I have sent a String(URL) from third Fragment to the First Fragment. First Fragment has a webView . I want to show website on the webView which I passes from third fragment./ But I am facing one problem It shows me Dialog to choose one browser rather than showing the URl on the webview. This is the code.

```
        String url="http://www.hotelsearcher.net/";
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args  != null){
        url = args.getString("url");
        }
//      url=FragmentC.url;
        WebView webView= (WebView) V.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in webview:

```
webViewSettings.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: You can change the question title to: "webView loadUrl opens browser choice dialog". Is more correctly.

Comment: I have changed the Title. 

Can you help me on this. Actually I am new to android development.:( 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565762/how-to-show-full-screen-loading-spinner-for-webview-in-android-fragment

Comment: This works for me. But in my case the ``setWebViewClient`` is not a member function of ``WebSettings`` but ``WebView`` itself.

Comment: shouldn't it be webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());