# Null Pointer exception on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I know this is a duplicate question but i am not able to find the correct on for me
I am trying to send some data from my OrderMadeFragment to OrderTakenFragment but I am not able to

here are my classes

**OrderMadeFragment**

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 *  on 12/22/2015.
 */
public class OrderMadeFragment extends Fragment
{
    SharedPreferences sh_pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor toEdit;
    Button b;
    EditText e;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_made, container, false);
        sh_pref=getContext().getSharedPreferences("start", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
        toEdit = sh_pref.edit();
        b=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        e=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String qv=e.getText().toString();
                OrderTakenFragment ldf = new OrderTakenFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("YourKey", qv);
                ldf.setArguments(args);
                Log.e("args", args.toString());

//Inflate the fragment
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**OrderTakenFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by on 12/22/2015.
 */
public class OrderTakenFragment extends Fragment
{
    TextView v;
    String bn="abc";
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_taken, container, false);
        v=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
//        String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
       // Log.e("YourKey",value);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                bn = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),bn,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Logcat Error**

```
12-23 11:17:11.811 10669-10669/com.example.qualwebs.test E/args: Bundle[{YourKey=Name}]
12-23 11:17:16.212 10669-10669/com.example.qualwebs.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.qualwebs.test, PID: 10669
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
   at com.example.qualwebs.test.OrderTakenFragment$1.onClick(OrderTakenFragment.java:31)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
```

I followed [How to send data from one Fragment to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment) link

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)'`

Comment: can u tell me what thing I am doing wrong
 i know what the error is

Comment: why `getArguments()` ?

Comment: for testing case ,comment out `bn = getArguments().getString("YourKey");`

Comment: `getArguments() == null == true`

Comment: I setArgument in my OrderMadeFragment class and I want to use that data in second class OrderTakenFragment
Can you guide me with proper answer 
I tried all possible solutions 

even this method also available on stackoverflow

Comment: you should probably use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` since you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Please post your XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your textview v has:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

In your  fragment OrderMadeFragment` :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Better still create a function in your containing activity:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.TheID, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Then from the fragment use:

```
((ContainingActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment(fragment);
```

This way you can manage your back stack and control your app navigation.

You need to manage your fragment args.

```
static final String YOUR_KEY = "YourKey";

private String key_;

public OrderTakenFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
 }


public static OrderTakenFragment newInstance(String key_) {
    OrderTakenFragment fragment = new OrderTakenFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(YOUR_KEY, key_);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        key_ = getArguments().getString(YOUR_KEY);
    }
}

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_taken, container, false);
    v=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(key_!=null)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),key_,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: on toast I  am getting null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98788/discussion-between-pritish-joshi-and-ms-yvette).

Answer (score 2):

You should request for arguments in ***onCreate()*** of your OrderTakenFragment

```
 String value;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(getArguments()!=null)
       value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");

 }
```

Then in your onCreateView(), under your onClick()

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          // Use the variable value in your toast
          if(value!=null)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am getting null on the other side in my fragment where i want to access data

Comment: can you confirm that you are not sending null as arguments ..and that you are receiving in the OrderTakenFragment's onCreate  null argument ..?

Comment: I am trying to getArguments on public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: And I have explicitly mentioned you need to get that under your onCreate() function. try there. Use a variable to store value in onCreate and then use it in your onCreateView().

Comment: yup able to get it in onCreate()
but when i tried to Toast it in OncreateView I am getting null

Comment: on toast i am getting null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98787/discussion-between-pritish-joshi-and-radix).

Answer (score 0):

U have to get data coming from fragment in a bundle like this :

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
bn = bundle.getString("YourKey", "abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to write these post as Answer.

First of all i think you want replace some `OrderMadeFragment` with `OrderTakenFragment` on same activity.

Try to change this line:

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();`

To:
`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, ldf).commit();`