# How to get bundle data from one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle

I have two fragments.addfragment and control fragment. From addfragment I send the data using bundle with fragment transaction and then in control fragment,I want to get that data using bundle but I can't get data. so plz help me

Here is my addfragment with fragment transaction-

```
     relaylist.setAdapter(adapter);
relaylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) relaylist.getItemAtPosition(position);



        Log.e("ip: ", "> " +  o.get("ip"));
        Log.e("port: ", "> " +  o.get("port"));
        Log.e("uname: ", "> " +  o.get("uname"));
        Log.e("password: ", "> " +  o.get("password"));


        ControlFragment fragment = new ControlFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ip", o.get("ip"));
        bundle.putString("port", o.get("port"));
        bundle.putString("uname", o.get("uname"));
        bundle.putString("password", o.get("password"));
        Log.e("ip: ", "> " +  o.get("ip"));
        Log.e("port: ", "> " +  o.get("port"));
        Log.e("uname: ", "> " +  o.get("uname"));
        Log.e("password: ", "> " +  o.get("password"));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new ControlFragment() );

        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

and In control fragment I get data this way...but I can't get data

```
public class ControlFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

             String ip=bundle.getString("ip");
            Stirng port = bundle.getString("port");
            Stirng uname = bundle.getString("uname");
            Stirng password = bundle.getString("password");
```

Comment: What  are you getting?did you debug?

Comment: I getting error like this...                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one Fragment to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting constructor instead of object. Use below code

```
ControlFragment fragment = new ControlFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ip", o.get("ip"));
        bundle.putString("port", o.get("port"));
        bundle.putString("uname", o.get("uname"));
        bundle.putString("password", o.get("password"));
        Log.e("ip: ", "> " +  o.get("ip"));
        Log.e("port: ", "> " +  o.get("port"));
        Log.e("uname: ", "> " +  o.get("uname"));
        Log.e("password: ", "> " +  o.get("password"));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment  );
```

**transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment  );**

This is change.

Answer (score 1):

Do the fetching data before oncreate view in oncreate.Always do a null check error before setting data.Hope this helps you

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String ip = bundle.getString("ip");
        String port = bundle.getString("port");
        String uname = bundle.getString("uname");
        String password = bundle.getString("password");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

As Amrish Kakadiya pointed out

transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, new ControlFragment());

This line of code is creating a problem, new ControlFragment() creates an entirely new instance of the fragment and hence you are getting the getArguments() as null while retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

use this line

Bundle bundle = getArguments();

before you inflater your rootview