# Passing multiple values from one fragment to another

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i'm pretty much stuck. I want to pass user input from the fields below
from one fragment, CarDetailsFragment to another fragment ConfirmationFragment. I also want to pass the states of the checkboxes(whether checked or unchecked). Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: use bundles for that

Comment: Use `interface` to communicating between fragments

Answer (score 0):

Use POJO class for this..

On Sending...

```
 YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putExtra("DATA", POJO_MODEL);
 ldf.setArguments(args);
```

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();

On Receiving...

```
POJO_MODEL pojo_model = POJO_MODEL_CAST)getArguments().getSerializable("DATA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bundle to send String:

//Put the value

```
   YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString("YourKey1", "YourValue");
   args.putString("YourKey2", "YourValue");
   ldf.setArguments(args);
```

//Inflate the fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

In onCreateView of the new Fragment:

//Retrieve the value

```
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Send data with `Bundle` as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
CarDetailsFragment carDetailsFragment = new CarDetailsFragment();
carDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);

//replace fragment  
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, carDetailsFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

and in `CarDetailsFragment`class  `onCreateView()` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String value  = getArguments().getString("key");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would recommend is to use a library like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

It's very lightweight and will make your life much easier. Please check the page I have linked above.

All you would need to do post an event and you create subscribe to those events in the whole app.