# Passing latitude and longitude from one fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments

**Maps and Fragments**

This is my design 
Image

[image]

I have two fragments.FirstFragment -> map and SecondFragment -> weather

I am getting Latitude and Longitude from First Fragment from the code below:

```
mPlace.setLatlng(place.getLatLng());
```

In the SecondFragment i am executing Latitude and Longitude on this code:

```
asyncTask.execute("10.873873","78.818729");
```

**Problem:** I wanted to pass Latitude and Longitude from my FirstFragment to SecondFragment.

And i tried Bundle with arguments to pass data.it does'nt work.

Comment: Passing latitude and longitude is no different than passing anything else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment

Comment: using bundle to pass my data is not working

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity will only have a single copy of each Fragment, then you can simply have the Activity hold the LatLng variable, and it will be accessable from both Fragments.

Comment: Thank u @lion.If i select a particular location in map(fragment1).i must get the weather of that location in my fragment2.Tried interfaces and bundle they does'nt work.Is any other way?? what are the steps???

Comment: @shyam notify the Activity, and have activity notify the fragment2.

Comment: Thank u i will notify @lionscribe