# I want to send data from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment

I want to send data from fragment to fragment using arguments the way I am doing is mentioned below.

*here's on button click data sent to fragment using argument*

```java
//sender fragment 
view.btnjavafragment.setOnClickListener {
            newInstance("helllo")
        }

  companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(mystring:String) = javaFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
              putString("sentdata",mystring)
              if(arguments!=null){
                  Toast.makeText(context,"data sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
              }
            }
        }
    }

//receiving fragment 
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        arguments?.getString("sentdata","")?.let {
            string = it
            tvdatamessage.setText(string)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one Fragment to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Please follow below link for your solutions.

https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments

You can also use Navigation Graph for Fragment Transaction and directly send any kind of data in bundle to send it like below.

```
var nameBundle = Bundle()
nameBundle.putString("youKey", edtName.text.toString())
it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.tofragmentName, nameBundle)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended that two Fragments should communicate directly. Check out the documentation and examples here. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

I would recommend a common ViewModel and observe the changes there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SafeArgs that are part of Navigation component on Jetpack.
[Here](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/7466f670-3d47-4b60-8f6a-0914ce58f9ad/concepts/e8ecc9a9-b393-4df2-bb5c-72827cc083a4) you have nice tutorial made by Google.