# How to pass data from fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, bundle

I have tried several times to send data from one fragment to another and it never works. I already used "Intent" and "Bundle" but nothing works. They said to use BroadCast Receiver, but there is little information on the Internet. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: What data are you trying to send?

Comment: i wuant pass Strings

Comment: Are your fragments hosted by the same activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one Fragment to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `intent` passing concept in fragment communication, fragments only accepts the `arguments` instead. Here is an simple example of fragment communication using `bundle`:

```
  YourReceiverFragment newFragment = new YourReceiverFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString("key1", data1);
  args.putString("key2", data1);
  newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

And get it from another (receiver) fragment inside the `onCreateView()` like:

```
String value1 = getArguments().getString("key1");
// and so on
```

But, Another good practice for fragment to fragment communication is to use `interfaces` via `Activity` like:

**SenderFragment**:

```
    public class SenderFragment extends Fragment {

    SenderFragmentListener mCommunication;
    public SenderFragment() {}// Required empty public constructor

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCommunication = (SenderFragmentListener) context;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sender, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sender);
        // on click button
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCommunication.messageFromSenderFragment("Hello Fragment i am Sender...");
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    //Interface for communication
    public interface SenderFragmentListener {
        void messageFromSenderFragment(String msg);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCommunication = null;
    }
}
```

**Activity**:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
        SenderFragment.SenderFragmentListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void messageFromSenderFragment(String msg) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ReceiverFragment mReceiverFragment = (ReceiverFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frg_Receiver);
        mReceiverFragment.youGotMsg(msg);
    }
}
```

**ReceiverFragment**:

```
    public class ReceiverFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv_msg;

    public ReceiverFragment(){} // Required empty public constructor

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receiver, container, false);
        tv_msg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_receiver);
        return view;
    }
    //Receive message
    public void youGotMsg(String msg) {
        tv_msg.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: You are sending data to the same fragment! Here is some edit on your sender fragment:
**
        String data1="ola";
        Parque_Fragment newFragment = new Parque_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("key1", data1);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        mContext = getActivity();
**
Replace it hope it will work.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Fragments don't communicate directly unless you use viewmodels. Here is a guide that can help you get started in working with fragments

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewmodel to share data between fragments, you can see detail in repo:
[enter link description here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5)

Answer (score 0):

Data can be passed between fragments using bundle

You have to write this in place where you are trying to change the fragment

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key_name1", value1);
bundle.putString("key_name2", value2);


FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
```

In FragmentB you can receive this data (you can write this in the onViewCreated() lifecycle of the fragment):

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {

value1=bundle.getInt("key_name1", 0); //0 is the default value , you can change that
value2=bundle.getString("key_name2",""); 
}
```