# Accessing same Firebase Firestore in multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

I have an `ArrayList<Person>` stored in `Firestore`.

I have a `RecyclerView` in **Fragment A** displaying the basic info of each person.

I have an `onClickListener` that replaces **Fragment A** with **Fragment B** and passes off the UID of the Person on Item clicked to **Fragment B** as well.

My goal with **Fragment B** is to display all of the details of the Person item clicked (and an option to add some more data) by somehow using the UID to get my data from `Firestore`.

My question is this, should I instantiate a `Firebase Firestore` for every `Fragment` that I need that same `Firestore` in?  Or can I pass off the Person object as a bundle (though I'm not sure if any changes I make reflect on Firebase).

I thought it was a very costly process and I'm not sure what my alternatives are.

Comment: first you will create the `Firebase Firestore` singleton object globally from that you will access the data. And while click on item pass the `UID` from the bundle and fetch the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. FirebaseFirestore is a [Singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%2C%20a,to%20the%20first%20instance%20created.) class which means that any where you call this:

> FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

You will always get the same object.

2. You can pass off the data to the second fragment if the Person class implements [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable). If it implements Parcelable you can add the person object to a bundle and send it to the other fragment [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24555520/14094533).
3. If by "instantiating Firestore" you actually mean retrieving your data from Firestore , Firestore locally [caches](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline#:%7E:text=Firestore%20supports%20offline%20data%20persistence,and%20query%20the%20cached%20data.) a copy of the data that your app is using, so fragment B will retrieve the data from the local cache.